# Parse variable to PHP from HTML FILE via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have basic html form in **html file (.html)** and basic php script. This is just for testing.

```
var first = $('#firstname').val();
var last = $('#lastname').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
var texts = $('#message').val();
$.ajax({
  url: "form/contact.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    first: first,
    last: last,
    email: email,
    texts: texts
  },

  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

PHP to send mail

```
<?php
   $message = $_POST['texts'];

   $to = "user@example.com";
   $subject = "Contact us";
   $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\n";

   mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

When my form is in html file I cannot parse variable with this code. But when I change file to .php everything works. How to make working with .html file?

Comment: You can't; for the same reason you can't use Python code in JavaScript. Different language, different file type.

Answer (score 2):

For parsing request of populating request data, **you need to use PHP file**. Because data is posted to server side script (PHP). You can not use HTML file it's client side language.

Comment: can you specify what error you got while parsing in the html file ?